# How to avoid three nested FOR loop grouped by two columns and also avoid the SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

In this dataframe I was wondering if there was a better and vectorized way to do this conditional operation between rows grouped by 'ID1' and 'ID2', rather than doing three nested FOR loops.

In addition, if there is a better way to avoid having this warning message, even when slicing with .loc as said:
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'TimeStamp' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
    'Id1': [80, 80, 80, 90, 90, 90, 100, 100, 100],
    'Id2': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 14, 12, 12], 
    'Col1': [3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1],
    'Col2': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'Col3': [110, 120, 130, 110, 120, 130, 110, 120, 130], 
    'Col4': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.sort_values(by='TimeStamp', ascending=True, inplace=True) 
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))

Output:
|   TimeStamp |   Id1 |   Id2 |   Col1 |   Col2 |   Col3 |   Col4 |
|------------:|------:|------:|-------:|-------:|-------:|-------:|
|           1 |    80 |    10 |      3 |      1 |    110 |      0 |
|           2 |    80 |    10 |      3 |      2 |    120 |      0 |
|           3 |    80 |    10 |      3 |      3 |    130 |      0 |
|           4 |    90 |    10 |      3 |      1 |    110 |      0 |
|           5 |    90 |    10 |      1 |      2 |    120 |      0 |
|           6 |    90 |    12 |      3 |      1 |    130 |      0 |
|           7 |   100 |    14 |      1 |      1 |    110 |      0 |
|           8 |   100 |    12 |      3 |      1 |    120 |      0 |
|           9 |   100 |    12 |      1 |      1 |    130 |      0 |
```

```
df_k=pd.DataFrame()
time_diff=125
for i in df['Id1'].unique():                   #loop same ID1
  df_i = df.loc[df['Id1']==i,:]                #df slice per ID1
  for j in df_i['Id2'].unique():               #loop same ID2
    df_j = df_i.loc[df_i['Id2']==j,:]          #df slice per ID2
    df_j.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) 
    for k, row in df_j.iterrows():            #loop all rows same ID and same Col1 
      if ((df_j.loc[k,'Col1']==1) & (df_j.loc[k,'Col3']>time_diff)): 
        break 
      elif ((df_j.loc[k,'Col1']==1) & (df_j.loc[k,'Col3']<time_diff)): 
        continue 
      elif ((df_j.loc[k,"Col1"]==3) & (df_j.loc[k,"Col3"]<time_diff)):   
        df_j.loc[k,"Col4"]=1                  #WARNING MESSAGE: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
                                              #A value is trying o be set on a copy of a df slice 
      else:                                   
        break
    df_k=pd.concat([df_j,df_k], ignore_index=True) #append df
df_k.sort_values(by='TimeStamp', ascending=True, inplace=True) 
print(df_k.to_markdown(index=False)) 

Output:
|   TimeStamp |   Id1 |   Id2 |   Col1 |   Col2 |   Col3 |   Col4 |
|------------:|------:|------:|-------:|-------:|-------:|-------:|
|           1 |    80 |    10 |      3 |      1 |    110 |      1 |
|           2 |    80 |    10 |      3 |      2 |    120 |      1 |
|           3 |    80 |    10 |      3 |      3 |    130 |      0 |
|           4 |    90 |    10 |      3 |      1 |    110 |      1 |
|           5 |    90 |    10 |      1 |      2 |    120 |      0 |
|           6 |    90 |    12 |      3 |      1 |    130 |      0 |
|           7 |   100 |    14 |      1 |      1 |    110 |      0 |
|           8 |   100 |    12 |      3 |      1 |    120 |      1 |
|           9 |   100 |    12 |      1 |      1 |    130 |      0 |
```

Thanks!

I ended up doing three FOR loop through the grouped dataframe's columns. But I was wondering if there was a better and vectorised way to set this value on these particular conditions. Also I would like to avoid having the SettingWithCopyWarning if there is a better way to carry out this operations.

Comment: Typically, `df.groupby(['ID1', 'ID2']).apply(...)` is going to be faster than looping over unique values of those two dataframes and filtering for matches. I would try that.

Comment: Thanks.
`df.groupby(['ID1', 'ID2']).apply(lambda x : my_check(x))`
with:
`def my_check(x):
  x.loc[((x['Col1'] == 3) & (x['Col3']<125)), 'Col4'] =1`
The issue is that it updates inside the lambda but not my original df. any thoughts?

Comment: You need to return the modified dataframe. `groupby()` will then concatenate all of the dataframes you return together, and provide it as a return value.